# unable to find initial jenkins password in docker logs -f command

Tags: docker, jenkins, automation

docker logs -f jenkins

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2019-07-26 11:31:22.358+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @736ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2019-07-26 11:31:22.543+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2019-07-26 11:31:22.583+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2019-07-26 11:31:22.669+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-05-02T00:04:53.875Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_222-b10
2019-07-26 11:31:23.095+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-07-26 11:31:23.164+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-07-26 11:31:23.164+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-07-26 11:31:23.168+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2019-07-26 11:31:23.936+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@1b66c0fb{Jenkins v2.187,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2019-07-26 11:31:23.956+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@380fb434{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-07-26 11:31:23.957+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @2335ms
2019-07-26 11:31:23.959+0000 [id=20]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
2019-07-26 11:31:26.546+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2019-07-26 11:31:26.633+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2019-07-26 11:31:28.711+0000 [id=28]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2019-07-26 11:31:28.719+0000 [id=28]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2019-07-26 11:31:28.770+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2019-07-26 11:31:29.252+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2019-07-26 11:31:29.340+0000 [id=41]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1#run: Started Download metadata
2019-07-26 11:31:29.381+0000 [id=41]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1#run: Finished Download metadata. 5 ms
2019-07-26 11:31:30.538+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#prepareRefresh: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@761809b1: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jul 26 11:31:30 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-07-26 11:31:30.538+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#obtainFreshBeanFactory: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@761809b1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7b79a184
2019-07-26 11:31:30.550+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory#preInstantiateSingletons: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7b79a184: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-07-26 11:31:30.877+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#prepareRefresh: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@3c22d8e4: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jul 26 11:31:30 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-07-26 11:31:30.877+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#obtainFreshBeanFactory: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@3c22d8e4]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c16e521
2019-07-26 11:31:30.878+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory#preInstantiateSingletons: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c16e521: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-07-26 11:31:31.042+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2019-07-26 11:31:31.233+0000 [id=19]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Comment: which version you are using? seems like you did not check the logs properly? just run in foreground like `docker run  jenkins/jenkins` you will the password

Comment: Please provide which docker image you are using.

Comment: yes I have used -d .

Comment: it worked without -d and I can see the password. Thank you

Comment: I ran into the same issue and it seems like this always happens when you trying using a different outer port mapping other than the default port mapping. I had some springboot app running on my localPc so I decided to use 8180:8080 instead of the default 8080:8080

docker run -p 8180:8080 -p 40000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts